# ResourceBundle - подключение файла

Tags: java, java-ee

Нужно подключить файл `properties` который лежит не рядом с классом где я использую `ResourceBundle`. Ложу файл рядом с классом всё работает.
Класс лежит в *src* - `ru.alex.Test.java`, а файлы мне нужно подключать из `web/lang`. Тобишь файлы `properties` находятся вне папки `src` Я использую `IDEA`. пытался прописывать пути к web - не получается подскажите такое можно сделать?

код:

```
ResourceBundle messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("ru.tsyklop.lang", currentLocale);
```

Answer (score 0):

Так смотри

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle("ru.tsyklop.lang", currentLocale);
```

это

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle("путь к файлу", название файла);
```

если файл лежит в другой директории, то пиши название этой директории.